# How to specify sourceCompatibility compile options when using the Android Gradle Experimental plugin

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-experimental, retrolambda

I'm currently using the Android Gradle Experimental plugin in one of my apps and I would like to be able to use the [retrolambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda) library.  One of the requirements is to specify some compileOptions.  In the normal android build plugin, this works:

```
  android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
  }
```

For the new Experimental plugin, I added this under model.android:

```
model {
  android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
  }
}
```

However, the above results in a gradle sync error:

```
Gradle 'ApkTestRunner' project refresh failed
Error:Cause: com.android.build.gradle.managed.AndroidConfig$Impl
```

How can I set sourceCompatibility and targetCompatibility using the new Android Experimental Gradle plugin?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Must be like this:

```
model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"
        compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1251'

       compileOptions.with {
         sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
         targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to add: this is in the android\app\build.gradle file and not in the root gradle file